# yii 2 widgets stopped working suddenly and not able to use anyone of them

Tags: yii2

I am using widgets from 2amigos and Karthik. Everything was working fine when one day, all widgets just stopped working. The DatePicker does not open, ckeditor does not look like the ckeditor and new widgets also do not work. Can anyone explain me how do I find out the root cause of the problem and solution for the same?

Comment: Did you update the packages? Do you get any errors?

Comment: "not working" is a really vague description... Can you please elaborate what's happening? The html is being generated? Does the page shows any error? If not, **i guess** you meant the javascripts are not running. If that's the case, you can open your browser's console and check if any js error appears. That's the best approach i can tell with the current info. Let me know how it goes or if that was any helpful.

Comment: @Alex: I have not updated the packages.

Comment: @CIyff: I use firebug to see if there are any errors but it shows none. "Not working" examples are DatePicker does not open to select a date, CKEditor does not show any of the advanced UI which it used to show before.

Comment: Do you have anything publicly accessible we can check?

Comment: This still looks like a problem with the js files.... In one of those views (or in your layout) try add a `var_dump(Yii::$app->assetManager)` and check if the assets listed in `bundles` are being called with the right css and js files. You can compare with the Asset file inside the vendor package or their repository on github. You can also check the page again if the js files are there and aren't empty for some reason.

Comment: Try to clear all assets and check errors again.

Comment: I fixed the problem. In "main.php" file under layouts, I had removed $this->head(), $this->beginBody(), $this->endBody(), $this->endPage() for some reason. There is an issue with the Assets as mentioned by @Clyff